# Is there a way to force Apache to Rewrite *without* trying to process subdirectory .htaccess files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Apache mod_rewrite doesn't work when sub-directory paths are inaccessible. My RewriteRules redirect requests for /shared-media to domain.s3.amazonaws.com/shared-media, but since the shared-media/ directory actually exists on my server, and Apache thinks it's inaccessible, it cannot read the sub-directory .htaccess file and therefore sends a 404.

**Is there a way to force Apache to Rewrite *without* trying to process subdirectory .htaccess files?**

Here's my basic directory structure:

```
/var/www/html <--- Document Root
  .htaccess
  index.php
  shared-media/  <--- Mount s3 bucket using s3fs
    IMG1.jpg
    IMG2.jpg
    thumbs/
      thumb1.jpg
      thumb2.jpg
```

For some reason the shared-media/ directory gets mounted by s3fs with some weird permissions:

```
# cd /var/www/html
# ls -la
total 212
drwxr-xr-x  5 webapp   webapp  4096 Oct 11 02:35 .
drwxrwxr-x  9 webapp   webapp  4096 Oct 11 05:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp   557 Oct 11 02:35 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 webapp   webapp   418 Oct 11 02:35 index.php
drwxrwxrwx  1 ec2-user webapp     0 Jan  1  1970 shared-media
# cd shared-media
# ls -l
total 66500
---------- 1 ec2-user webapp    82797 Sep 25 15:08 IMG1.jpg
---------- 1 ec2-user webapp  5826073 Oct  4 20:48 IMG2.pdf
d--------- 1 ec2-user webapp        0 Oct 10 18:16 thumbs
# cd thumbs
# ls -l
total 4323
---------- 1 ec2-user webapp    2797 Sep 25 15:08 thumb1.jpg
---------- 1 ec2-user webapp   26073 Oct  4 20:48 thumb2.pdf
```

My PHP upload script still works in that it can save images to both the shared-media/ directory and the shared-media/thumbs/ directory. And actually moving around the file system as ec2-user still works. But Apache doesn't attempt to `cd` into the directory, it apparently does a permissions check and since the permissions are weird it thinks that it can't get there. Once it determines that, it sends a 404.

Here's the response code:

```
wget http://domain/shared-media/thumbs/thumb1.jpg
--2014-10-11 07:58:17--  http://domain/shared-media/thumbs/thumb1.jpg
Resolving domain ... 5.12.2.15
Connecting to domain|5.12.2.15|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-10-11 07:58:18 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

And here's the HTML error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /shared-media/thumbs/thumb1.jpg
on this server.<br />
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe</p>
</body></html>
```

**Is there a way to have the root .htaccess do an immediate Rewrite WITHOUT trying to process sub-directory .htaccess files?**

My root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shared-media/(.*)$ http://www.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/shared-media/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Version information:

```
# cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03
Kernel \r on an \m

# uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-1-142 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 2 09:36:59 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Amazon)
Server built:   Jul 30 2014 23:57:26

# s3fs --version
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System V1.78 with OpenSSL
Copyright (C) 2010 Randy Rizun <rrizun@gmail.com>
License GPL2: GNU GPL version 2 <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.     

# pkg-config --modversion fuse
2.9.3
```

Comment: I think all the essential information is in this question. I sadly lack the knowledge to answer it though.